# How do I make pasted shell commands invisible?

Tags: stdout, putty, stdin, csh

I'm using an AutoHotkey macro to run some shell commands, *i.e.*

```
^`::
SendInput set c=".cshrc-acheong"{ENTER}
SendInput set v=".vimrc-acheong"{ENTER}
SendInput foreach d ( /home/acheong /home/tcama /userhome/andrew.cheong ){ENTER}
SendInput if ( -e $d/$c ) source $d/$c{ENTER}
SendInput if ( -e $d/$v ) alias vim "vim -N -u $d/$v"{ENTER}
SendInput end{ENTER}
return
```

If you're not familiar with AutoHotkey, no problem—it's the same as pasting several lines of shell commands at once—and many of us have seen how the command prompt appears "asynchronously" as each line executes:

[image]

**Is there a command or trick to hiding (perhaps blocking) `stdin` and then executing the input without displaying it (or its outputs)?** Sort of like typing passwords.

---

Please be sparing of judgments regarding the above :-( To preemptively disclaim some things:

1. I don't use `csh` by choice; yes, I've read the Top 10.
2. I work with hundreds of servers that don't all mount the same network share for `/home`—that's why I'm using `rsync` to push a "master" `.cshrc` and `.vimrc` to a location per distinct network share, so that the above keyboard macro will find and load whichever is found, wherever I am.

---

**Update**

I tried adding `stty -echo`, *i.e.*

```
^`::
SendInput stty -echo{ENTER}
SendInput set c=".cshrc-acheong"{ENTER}
SendInput set v=".vimrc-acheong"{ENTER}
SendInput foreach d ( /home/acheong /home/tcama /userhome/andrew.cheong ){ENTER}
SendInput if ( -e $d/$c ) source $d/$c{ENTER}
SendInput if ( -e $d/$v ) alias vim "vim -N -u $d/$v"{ENTER}
SendInput end{ENTER}
SendInput stty echo{ENTER}
return
```

However the prompts continue to appear:

[image]

(I thought about unsetting `$prompt` but I'm reluctant as one of the things my `.cshrc` does is precisely to replace `$prompt`.)

Comment: Just an idea: put small wait statements between `SendInput` commands so that the shell can react before it gets new input.

Comment: @jofel - AHK provides such a command, `Sleep`, but in this case I'd like to hide what's happening regardless, even if it formats nicely. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with AutoHotKey, so if you can't find any solution there, read on.

POSIX specifies [the `read` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html), which allows taking a line of input while stifling the terminal echo (that's what you see when you type) with `-s`.  This is also a bash built-in, but you might check your system to see if it is present as a standalone.

Otherwise, [looking here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694016/csh-scripting-for-password-authorisation-of-user), you can accomplish the the same thing using `stty` (another standalone) with csh:

```
stty -echo # turn echo off
# do your input
stty echo # turn echo back on
```

Comment: AutoHotKey is a Windows hack-language. You don't *want* to be any more familiar with it than that, I promise you.

Answer (score 2):

You can get pretty close to what you want by using the alternate screen buffer.
Most *(all?)* terminal emulators have 2 screen buffers that you can switch between. So you switch to the alternate screen buffer, run your commands, and then switch back to the main one.

Just run the following before your commands:

```
tput smcup
```

And at the end, run

```
tput rmcup
```

However this will still show the `tput smcup` command on the screen.
The only way I can think of hiding the command is to add a key binding to it (like <kbd>ESC</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>). I know `zsh` can do this, but I do not know about `csh`.

---

If you do not have the `tput` command, you can echo out the raw escape codes.
For putty, this would be:

```
echo -e '\e[?47h'
```

and

```
echo -e '\e[2J\e[?47l'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `mkfifo` a bidirectional `|pipe` between the two machines and write to it instead of relying on pasting into a putty terminal. But if you must use putty, then you should turn off its flow control in the settings and use raw mode - `stty raw` on the host side and find the raw terminal option in putty's settings.